# What is the physical interpretation of Lorentz boosts not commuting?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, group-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

My professor is talking about how Lorentz boosts do not commute and how it relates to Thomas Precession, but I am struggling to wrap my head around the implications of that and how it works. Also confused about how commutation in general is applied to areas other than quantum mechanics.

Comment: Commutation is all about testing if the order of things matter. They don't just appear in quantum mechanics. Take the braid group for example on some number of strings. Non-commutativity there is telling you something about which ways to braid can be done in any order to achieve the same result.

Comment: Related :  **(1)** [Combining two Lorentz boosts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480463/combining-two-lorentz-boosts/618002#618002). **(2)** [General matrix Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361227/general-matrix-lorentz-transformation/361317#361317).
**(3)** [Show that any proper homogeneous Lorentz transformation may be expressed as the product of a boost times a rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588883/show-that-any-proper-homogeneous-lorentz-transformation-may-be-expressed-as-the/615778#615778).

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_precession). [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395036/composition-of-lorentz-transformations-using-generators-and-the-wigner-rotation).

Answer (score 5):

Boosts are [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Proper_transformations) Lorentz transformations, so are rotations (defined herein as determinant-$1$ metric-preserving linear transformations) in Minkowski spacetime. Just like rotations in Euclidean space, the order matters.

Consider a vector pointing along $x$. If you rotate about $x$, it does nothing. So if you rotate about $x$ and then about $y$ you get a different outcome than if you rotate about $y$ and then $x$.

This is the physical interpretation. A boost is legitimately a rotation in spacetime.

Comment: Dale, this is an excellent explanation I had never grasped before. You have done me, at age 70, a valuable service!

Comment: I've edited in the requested precision about rotation terminology, then flagged as no longer needed several existing comments.

Comment: @WillO the Minkowski metric is not a metric though, which is why boosts indeed don't _quite_ fit the definition of a rotation.