# Wigner Rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, lie-algebra

I'm trying to show that the composition of two Lorentz boosts produces a boost and a rotation using the generators from the Lorentz Group. If $\vec{K}$ denotes the Lorentz Boost generators and $\vec{S}$ denotes the rotation generators then two successive Lorentz Boosts in the $x$- and then $y$-directions is given by $$e^{-\xi_yK_y}e^{-\xi_xK_x}$$ How do I go on from here to prove the result is another boost and a rotation? I know I have to make use of the commutator $$[K_i,K_j]=-\epsilon_{ijk}S_k$$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Related : [General matrix Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361227/)

Comment: [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395036/composition-of-lorentz-transformations-using-generators?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are meant to compose the two exponentials of the noncommuting boost generators, possibly by the [CBH expansion identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_explicit_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), or else by simply expanding each exponential to a few low orders in the *ξ* rapidity parameters, as the [WP article suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation#Group_theoretical_origin), and utilize the commutators. In your case, you need $[K_y,K_x]=S_z$, $[K_y,S_z]=-K_x$, and $[K_x,S_z]=K_y$, which happen to close to an SU(2)!

That is, to say,
$$ e^{-\xi_yK_y}e^{-\xi_xK_x}\\ = \Large e^{-\xi_yK_y-\xi_xK_x +\frac{\xi_y\xi_x}{2} [K_y,K_x]- \frac{\xi_y\xi_x}{12}(\xi_y [K_y,[K_y,K_x]] + \xi_x [K_x,[K_x,K_y]]  )+... }\\= \Large e^{-\xi_yK_y-\xi_xK_x +\frac{\xi_y\xi_x}{2} S_z+ \frac{\xi_y\xi_x}{12}(\xi_y  K_x + \xi_x K_y  )+... }
~~.$$
In point of fact, the $O(\xi^4)$ term in the exponent vanishes in this particular case, and the leading non-vanishing one is $O(\xi^5)$, which you could easily compute.

There is a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) for such an SU(2) expression, (or, better, the [Gibbs composition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rodrigues_parameters_and_Gibbs_representation)), so a linear combination of the three generators with coefficients to *all* orders in *ξ*. The complete expression is a product of a boost and a Wigner rotation, $\exp(\theta S_z)\exp(a K_y +b  K_x)   $, with   $\tan \theta= (\sinh \xi_x \sinh \xi_y )/(\cosh \xi_x +\cosh \xi_y)$, and $a(\xi_y, \xi_x)$ and $b(\xi_x, \xi_y)$ messy Gibbs parameters, and amounts to an SU(2) group identity. (Observe this ordering elements, when combined as above, yields the composite single element found above, to this order in the *ξ*s, $\exp(\xi_x\xi_y S_Z/2+...) =\exp (\xi_y K_y/3 -\xi_x K_x/3+...) $,  where the lagging new composite boost is asymmetric in *x* and *y*, as it should be!)

To sum up, combining two boosts along different axes *x* and *y* produces a Lorentz transformation which is not just a pure boost, the $O(\xi)$ sum of boosts, but also an $O(\xi^2)$ rotation, the Wigner rotation underlying the Thomas precession.

You may also observe that, if you undid these two boosts in the same order, you would get a doubled Wigner rotation as the leading, $O(\xi^2)$, remnant,
$$
e^{-\xi_yK_y}e^{-\xi_xK_x}  e^{\xi_yK_y}e^{\xi_xK_x} \\ =   e^{
  \xi_y\xi_x [K_y,K_x]  +  O(\xi^3) +... }=  e^{
  \xi_y\xi_x  S_z  +  O(\xi^3) +... } ~~.
$$
This is called the group commutator, whose logarithm is the corrected Lie algebra commutator, a  double Wigner rotation.