# Find angle from two perpendicular relativistic Lorentz boosts

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

I have a frame $s'$ moving with velocity $v_1$ along the x-direction with respect to a frame $s$. A frame $s''$ is moving with velocity $v_2$ along the y-direction with respect to $s'$.

I want to find the Lorentz transformation matrix from $s$ to $s''$, which I have below, just from multiplying the matrices with the corresponding boosts.

Note: I'm working in c=1 units. The first matrix is the boost from $s'$ to $s''$ in y, and the second is the boost from $s$ to $s'$ in x.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\gamma_{2}} & {0} & {-v_{2} \gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} \\ {-v_{2} \gamma_{2}} & {0} & {\gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\gamma_{1}} & {-v_{1} \gamma_{1}} & {0} & {0} \\ {-v_{1} \gamma_{1}} & {\gamma_{1}} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\gamma_{1} \gamma_{2}} & {-v_{1} \gamma_{1} \gamma_{2}} & {-v_{2} \gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {-v_{1} \gamma_{1}} & {\gamma_{1}} & {0} & {0} \\ {-v_{2} \gamma_{2} \gamma_{1}} & {v_{1} v_{2} \gamma_{1} \gamma_{2}} & {\gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right]$$

Now let's say that we are working with a "boat problem", so that frame $s$ is a person on a riverbank, $s'$ is the rest frame of water moving with $v_1$ along the x-direction, and $s''$ is the rest frame of a boat traveling with $v_2$ perpendicular to the water's motion. I want to find the angle ($\phi = arctan(y/x)$) that the boat makes with respect to the shore. I know to use my final matrix, and I know that the second and third rows respectively correspond to y and x, but I am not sure how to find the equations for y and x to plug into my angle formula.

Comment: Two Lorentz boosts in different directions are equivalent to a single boost followed by a rotation or a rotation followed by a single boost. So the result involves *various* different angles. First there is the angle of the [Thomas-Wigner rotation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation). Second, there is the direction of the resultant boost, but that depends on whether you first boost or rotate. So your question is ill-posed.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401713/wigner-rotation) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395036/composition-of-lorentz-transformations-using-generators-and-the-wigner-rotation?noredirect=1&lq=1).