# Special Relativity - Perpendicular Boosts Equaling to a Rotation after a Boost

Tags: special-relativity

**[Question]**
I recently read that two perpendicular Lorentz boosts equal to a rotation after a boost. Can anyone here show me an example of this happening? Thank you for your time and assistance!

*Source: None - (not a homework question)*

Comment: I think OP is asking for a concrete worked example, but [this SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401713/wigner-rotation?rq=1) appears to do the general case using the commutation relations for the generators of the Lorentz algebra. So very relevant, but possibly not a duplicate.

Comment: @jacob1729 ,while I really appreciate your reply as well as providing me the topic-related link, I - unfortunately - don't have the required mathematical (and special relativity) competency to understand what's going on in that post. I was looking more along the lines of a matrix example but I haven't gotten any luck finding one yet ...
Regardless, thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't have time to write out a full answer but as an exercise for the OP: consider a rod aligned with the $x$ axis and moving in the $+y$ direction. Boost to a new frame $S'$ moving along $x$ at speed $\beta$ in $S$. You should see that the rod is not parallel to the $x'$ axis.

Comment: @jacob1729 , thank you for taking the time to help me! I sincerely appreciate it. I now have a slightly better idea how two perpendicular Lorentz boosts equal to a rotation after a boost. I'll be sure to think about your comment and see how should I provide my example for the question. Otherwise, to reinforce my understanding of what you have stated here, I'll still try my best to find an example of the OP here.

Comment: Related : [General matrix Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361227/general-matrix-lorentz-transformation/361317#361317).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explicit example. The matrix rows and columns are in the usual order $t,x,y,z$.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{4 \sqrt{3}}{7} & -\frac{1}{7} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{4 \sqrt{3}}{7} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{4}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
 -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{25}{21} & \frac{2}{7 \sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{7 \sqrt{3}} & \frac{8}{7} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I will let you confirm the equality, and that the left-hand-side represents a boost by $c/2$ along the $x$-direction followed by a boost by $c/2$ along the $y$-direction, and that the right-hand-side represents a boost by $\sqrt{7}c/4$ in the direction $(2/\sqrt{7},\sqrt{3/7},0)$ followed by rotation around the $z$-axis by $\cos^{-1}(4\sqrt{3}/7)$ or $8.21$ degrees.

It helps to have the [formula for a general boost matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Proper_transformations), which is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \gamma & -\gamma \beta n_x & -\gamma \beta n_y & -\gamma \beta n_z \\
 -\gamma \beta n_x & 1+(\gamma-1)n_x^2 & (\gamma-1)n_xn_y & (\gamma-1)n_xn_z \\
 -\gamma \beta n_y & (\gamma-1)n_yn_x & 1+(\gamma-1)n_y^2 & (\gamma-1)n_yn_z \\
 -\gamma \beta n_z & (\gamma-1)n_zn_x & (\gamma-1)n_zn_y & 1+(\gamma-1)n_z^2 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

To get a [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation), the two boosts don't have to be perpendicular; they just have to be non-colinear. Their composition can also be expressed as a rotation followed by a boost, rather than a boost followed by a rotation. If you express the composition of the boosts as a rotation followed by boost, the resulting rotation will be the same as before, but the resulting boost will be different. For example,

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{4}{3} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{2}{3} & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{8}{7} & \frac{2}{7 \sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
 -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{7 \sqrt{3}} & \frac{25}{21} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{4 \sqrt{3}}{7} & -\frac{1}{7} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{4 \sqrt{3}}{7} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now the boost direction is $(\sqrt{3/7},2/\sqrt{7},0)$.

If you do the two original boosts in the opposite order, you'll get different results since they don't commute.

ADDENDUM: Wondering how to decompose the product of a general Lorentz transformation into a boost and a rotation? See [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516020/special-relativity-how-to-tell-a-new-boosts-magnitude-direction-and-rotatio/516126#516126).

Comment: @Athenian I fixed a typo in the formula for the general boost matrix. One of the subscripts on an $n$ was wrong. If that caused you to have problems verifying the example, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me of the changes! Your explanation was incredibly clear and I sincerely appreciate the effort you went through to provide me such a stellar example! Thanks to this, I was able to learn a lot regarding Lorentz boosts and transformations.